# My InputBox is not being evaluated...Code runs, but the code seems to jump right over it

Tags: excel, vba

my code seems to compile, and run correctly, but for some reason the Inputbox does not seems to be evaluated at all. The Inputbox is in the middle of the code, what I am trying to accomplish is to have a cells data evaluated against a MonthName, and if its a match then spit out a Inputbox to the User. The function it is evaluating is:

```
 =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A3,'G:\Financial\Facility Work Papers and Financials\1. 
 Operating Entities\Arbors\2. Financials\2018\5. May\[Arbors May 2018.xls]Trial 
 Balance'!$A$30:$H$100,8,FALSE),0)
```

Here is the code:

```
Sub Date1()

    Dim r As Range
    Dim s As String
    Dim UserInput As String
    Dim Curdate As Date
    Dim newDate As String
    Dim newDate1 As String
    Dim newDate2 As String
    Dim newDate3 As String
    Dim LastCol As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim k As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    With ActiveSheet
        For k = 1 To 12
            Curdate = CDate(k & " " & "01," & " " & "2018")

            newDate1 = MonthName(Month(Curdate), False)
            newDate2 = MonthName(Month(Curdate), True)
            newDate3 = Month(Curdate)
            newDate = newDate3 & "." & newDate2

            Debug.Print newDate
            Debug.Print newDate1
            'Defining the loops parameteres

            For Each r In ActiveSheet.Range("D3:D6").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
                s = LCase(r.Formula)
                If InStr(1, r, newDate1) > 0 Then

                    UserInput = Application.InputBox(prompt:=newDate1 & "is the current data, if this is the data you want", Title:="please click cancel, otherwise click OK", Default:=newDate1)

                End If
            Next r
        Next k

        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To LastCol
            For j = 1 To LastRow
                With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

                    .Range(.Cells(j, 1), .Cells(1, i)).Replace What:=oldDate3 & "." & " " & oldDate2, replacement:=newDate, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
                    .Range(.Cells(j, 1), .Cells(1, i)).Replace What:=oldDate1, replacement:=newDate1, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False

                End With
            Next j
        Next i
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Debug.Print Curdate
    Debug.Print newDate3 & "." & newDate2
    Debug.Print newDate1
    Debug.Print newDate

End Sub
```

[image: The function I am evaluating]

Comment: One issue is the If statement just before the InputBox.  InStr evaluates 2 strings, and you are passing a Range and a String.

Comment: `CurDate` would be better defined as `Curdate = DateSerial(2018, 1, k)` and you should define `oldDate1`, `oldDate2` and `oldDate3`.

Comment: @Brian M Stafford -  Hmm, I replaced "r" with "s" in the  `If InStr(1, r, newDate1) > 0 Then` and it does still does not recognize the InputBox...

Comment: Looking through your code I think there's a much easier way to do it - just not sure what you're trying to do.  E.g. From what I can see you've defined `newDate` as various ways to view the same date, but you could just use (taking todays date for the example):  `FORMAT(DATE(),"mmmm")`, `FORMAT(DATE(),"mmm")`, `FORMAT(DATE(),"m")` and `FORMAT(DATE(),"d.mmm")` to get your four `newDate` values.  You're then checking if the month name is in the text of the formula and asking if that's the data you want and then irrespective of what they answer you replace some dates in the `Data` sheet.....

Comment: .... so what's it meant to be doing?

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook - That is a good point, it will make my code much simpler and shorter; thanks. From the beginning of my code until `Next k` is just to let the User know what Month's data is currently in the worksheet. The next part of the code, you can just dismiss because I need to change it.

Comment: So - the range is greater than `D3:D6` and that range holds dates?  You want to list the month names from those dates and get the user to select a specific month which will be actioned on?

Comment: I changed the code to this: `ActiveSheet.Range("D3").Cells.SpecialCells (xlCellTypeFormulas)
        s = LCase(r.Formula)
        If InStr(1, s, newDate1) > 0 Then` I want the code to evaluate just this one cell, and if the monthname of the current iteration of the loop, lets say May, matches the string in the formula "May" then propmt the user with a inputbox giving the option to the user to cancel or continue on to the next part which will change it to the month they need. ( This part I have done already, I just need to update it)